# Canceling a Google Cloud Build job via "gcloud builds cancel" reports successful status (green checkmark)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On several of my Google Cloud projects that utilize Google Cloud Build I have a condition where if a certain check fails twice I then cancel the build via the "gcloud builds cancel" cmd:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/cancel

What confuses me is that when this happens, Google Cloud Build reports the build as "successful":

[image: google cloud build successful status]

Yet in this specific situation where I'm manually cancelling the build I would want it to instead show the red checkmark / failed status:

[image: google cloud build failed status]

Seems like a pretty uncommon issue out there as my research hasn't yielded any real results. And it's frustrating to not really know if there was a failure on first glance until I dig into the logs or something just isn't working as expected.

Anyone with some insight on how I could more accurate cause a build to fail and display a "failed"/red-checkmark status would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `gcloud builds cancel` command executes while the build command is still configuring your build steps.
I think you might find [this document](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order) really helpful as it demonstrates and has examples on how the build step orderly executes. As a summary, by default, build steps run sequentially, but you can also configure them to run concurrently. The steps are dependent on every id on the `waitfor` configuration flag.
This  just means that the build steps run serialy and attain the success state during this Waitfor condition, if the build is canceled during this time frame , it might affect the state transition process and result in this ambiguity.